# Flask: Contact Page formatting with bootstrap 3

Tags: python, html, twitter-bootstrap, flask

This is my first time using Flask and I have created the form for the visitors to fill out, but I want to use the bootstrap formatting so its looks similar to another form I am using in the website. Im not sure how I can link the form together. Here is my code for the contact.html page:

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% block content %}

<div class="content fixed-height">

    <h3> {{ title }} </h3>

    <!--<form action="http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/contact.php" method="post">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Your Name *</label>
            <input type="text" name="cf_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name" required autofocus/>
        </div>


        <div class="controls-group">
            <label class="control-label"> Your e-mail *</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="email" name="cf_email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email" required/>

                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Message *</label>
            <textarea name="cf_message" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Message" rows="6" required></textarea>

        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="reset" value="Clear" class="btn btn-primary">

      </form> -->

     <form action="{{ url_for('contact') }}" method=post
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

        {{ form.name.label }}
        {{ form.name }}

        {{ form.email.label }}
        {{ form.email }}

        {{ form.subject.label }}
        {{ form.subject }}

        {{ form.message.label }}
        {{ form.message }}

        {{ form.submit }}
    </form>
</div>


{% endblock %}
```

The first part of the contact.html page is an old form that I was using and is in comment tags. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using the WTF Flask extension for working with forms?

Flask also has a Bootstrap extension that you can install using pip:

```
pip install flask-bootstrap
```

You can then import it and into the module that your Flask application instance has been created in:

```
from flask.ext.bootstrap import Bootstrap

app = Flask(__name__)
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)
```

This will provide you with some great functionality including a helper method that you can use to quickly generate forms in your HTML templates.

Go to the page where you want to generate the form and after your extends statement do the following:

```
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}  # imports the form template elements



# where you want your form to be
{{ wtf.quick_form(form) }} #the method takes the form argument from your view function
```

This will generate a form for you. You can read more about the [Bootstrap extension here](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Bootstrap/). Go to the Templates page and look for the section of Forms. Good luck!

Comment: Cheers that was very helpful managed to get it sorted! Didn't even know there was an extension for bootstrap :D